# gdal.Open error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Tags: python, gdal, osgeo

I am running a python script which calibrates a hydrologic model, this script uses gdal from Osgeo. Following is the command I am giving python:

```
from osgeo import gdal
infile="G:\ARORA\vic_inputs\routing_files\new_basin\sutlej_beas_new_fraction.tif"
ds = gdal.Open(infile,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)
```

b1 gives the following error:

`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-ba605a73e25c> in <module>()
----> 1 b1 = ds.GetRasterBand(band)`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'`

The type(ds) returns NoneType.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I just capitalised tif in the path. It got solved that way.
So try replacing `tif` as `TIF`.

Also write the path in `r""` so that you don't have to change the `\`.
See the documentation: [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that your file exists by using:

```py
import os
if not os.path.isfile(infile):
   raise FileNotFoundError(f"Non existing {infile}")
```

This way, you will directly see if your file is found or not, and if there is a problem with your string.

I agree, on Windows, always use raw strings ( `r""`) to be sure your `\` will be used as separator.
However, I don't understand the capitalized TIF part, you must use the syntax your file has!